# Fatal error: gtk--.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, gtk

My name is Sebastian. I am trying to compile a project under Ubuntu 20. This project is for sending data to a Timex Datalink via a µc (link: https://github.com/dfries/datalink_ironman). In this Github repository is a folder name "graph". Inside this folder is a c++ source file (fun.cc) and a make file. When I open the terminal inside this folder and enter "make" I get the error message "Fatal error: gtk--.h: No such file or directory".
But gtk is installed. The command "pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags"gives the output:

> -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16

Has someone an idea how to compile this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program is probably using a very old version of gtkmm from when it was still named gtk--: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/FAQ#Why_is_it_named_gtkmm.3F

I would expect to have to do some updates to get it to work with even the most recent version of gtkmm 2.x.

Comment: With update, you mean rewriting the code?

Comment: There would likely be some amount of changes necessary, but would not require rewriting the whole code.